# Formatear String

Tags: java, android, string

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
String convertedString = new DecimalFormat("##.###.###,##")
    .format(Double.parseDouble(Constantes.TRANSACCION_MONTO));
TXTTRANSMONTO.setText(convertedString);
```

¿Cómo hago para que no se me crashee la app? Me da error.

La constante `TRANSACCION_MONTO` es string con valor 150000, pero dese que se muestre 150,000.00

Comment: Jesus, como un tip, trata siempre de agregar detalles de tu pregunta, especifica valores de variables, y en caso el error que se muestra (en Android usa el LogCat) para que tengas mejor respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Que valor tiene `TRANSACCION_MONTO`?

Comment: tiene un valor numerico que traigo desde un editext pero que he almacenado en esa variable. lo declaro como TRANSACCION_MONTO = ttmonto.getText().toString();

Comment: @JesusMoran trata de ser más especifico y aportar siempre lo datos necesarios, esto para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso es importante tener un valor adecuado que sea transformado por el patrón definido que en este caso es `"##.###.###,##"` de lo contrario tendrás un `IllegalArgumentException` que puede ser una causa del cierre de tu aplicación.

Otra causa es que si estas realizando una conversión a Double, primeramente asegura que el valor String a convertir en realidad sea numérico, de otra forma tendrías error `NumberFormatException`.

---

Comentas que el valor de `TRANSACCION_MONTO` es "150000", y deseas se muestre "150,000.00" , para esto el patron correcto para aplicar el formato debe ser "###,###.00"

Ejemplo:

```
 String convertedString = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00")
                .format(Double.parseDouble(TRANSACCION_MONTO));
```

de esta forma convertedString  tendrá un valor :

```
 150,000.00
```

Answer (score -1):

Una forma muy sencilla de convertir cualquier valor a String, es concatenarlo con una cadena de texto o hasta con dos comillas vacias, la cuestion es concatenarlo.

Ej:

```
int numero = 256;
String texto = "" + numero;

// En este caso imprimiria el número como una cadena de texto.
Log.i("log", texto);
```

Puede ser cualquier tipo de valor, como por ejemplo un valor booleano:

```
boolean condicion = true;
String texto2 = "" + condicion;

// En este caso imprimiria el valor booleano como una cadena de texto.
Log.i("log", texto2);
```